# D3.js não mostra nada na tela

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapas

Estou tentando usar o D3.js mas não estou conseguindo. Tenho o código abaixo, mas ele não imprime o mapa do Brasil. A tela não mostra nenhum erro, o que poderia ser? o meu arquivo "meso.json" está no formato topojSON mas ele transforma o topojSON em GeoJson já no código do d3.js:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D3.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var width = 900,
                height = 650;

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([55,10])
            .scale(750);

            var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

            queue()
            .defer(d3.json, "topo/meso.json")
            .await(ready);

            function ready(error, br_mesos){

                if(error) return console.error(error);

                var mesos = topojson.feature(br_mesos, br_mesos.objects.meso);

                svg.append("path")
                .datum(mesos)
                .attr('d', path)
                .attr('class', 'mesos');

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Veja se tem algum erro no console. Não consegui simular devido ao `"topo/meso.json"`. Nos ajudaria se pudesse fornecê-lo.

Comment: é uma pasta chamada "topo" que tem esse arquivo json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o "meso.json" contém apenas o mapa do Brasil, é provável que ele esteja aparecendo sim, mas fora da área de visualização.

Pelas coordenadas geográficas que você está usando (latitude 10, longitude 55) o centro está no hemisfério norte e oriental (provavelmente África, Ásia, Índia ou algum lugar no meio do Oceano Índico. O Brasil fica entre as latitudes +5 e -34 e longitudes -34 a -74 e por isso não deve estar aparecendo no mapa.

Para verificar isto, reduza a escala para 150 (que cabe o mundo inteiro) e veja se o mapa aparece.

Eu imagino que você deve ter trocado os sinais, pois [-55,-10] (em vez de [55,10]) é um bom centro para o mapa do Brasil.

Troque por `.center([-55,-10])` e veja se o mapa aparece.

Eu joguei seu código em um [JSFiddle][https://jsfiddle.net/mg2rq15x/] onde você pode experimentar com um mapa do mundo, e depois trocar pelo mapa que você está usando. Eu comentei seu código em dois lugares para poder usar esste exemplo.